# VBA to Close Current Form and Return to a Different Form on New Record

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have two forms in my access database, "Adjustment Form" and "Final Form". 
On "Final Form", there is a button that when clicked, I would like it to close the current form and open the Adjustment Form to a new record.

FYI- The Adjustment Form will likely already be open, so if this is the case, just close the "Final Form" and move to a new record.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Private Sub Command438_Click()
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
    DoCmd.Close
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , "Adjustment Form", , acNewRec
End Sub
```

However, when I run this, I get the error "You can't go to the specified record".

Any idea how to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a command button on "AdjustmentForm" and name it "cmdAddRec". Have this create a new record when clicked. You can add things to the coding in the command button such as go to a control where you want to input data. Then amend your code to:

```
Private Sub Command438_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Adjustment Form"
    cmdAddRec_Click
    DoCmd.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: but if you execute a open form, and then your next line of cmdAddRec_Clink will run code in the current form - not form Adjustment. So I can't see how this will work.

Comment: Agreed. My answer needs to be dleted.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```
  Dim f       As String

  f = "frmAdjustMent"     ' name of form to open

  ' save record
  If Me.Dirty = True Then Me.Dirty = False

  ' check if Adjustent form is open
  ' (if not, then open it)
  If CurrentProject.AllForms(f).IsLoaded = False Then
     DoCmd.OpenForm f
  End If

  DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, f, acNewRec

  ' close current form

  DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
```